# spring controlleradvice is not catching aexpirerJwtException

Tags: spring-boot, exception, unauthorized, controller-advice

@ExceptionHandler(DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
public ResponseEntity handleRegisterUsernameDuplication(DataIntegrityViolationException e){
ErrorObject errorObject = new ErrorObject(
HttpStatus.CONFLICT.value(),
e.getMessage(),
new Date()
);
return new ResponseEntity<>(errorObject, HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
}

```
    @ExceptionHandler(ExpiredJwtException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorObject> handleJwtExpiration(ExpiredJwtException e){
        ErrorObject errorObject = new ErrorObject(
                HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(),
                e.getMessage(),
                new Date()
        );
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorObject, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
}
```

But when the token expires, the `403` error(forbidden) is used instead of my defined `401` (Unauthorized), from server:

```
2023-12-06T17:01:13.459+01:00 ERROR 11489 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException: JWT expired at 2023-12-06T16:01:12Z. Current time: 2023-12-06T16:01:13Z, a difference of 1457 milliseconds.  Allowed clock skew: 0 milliseconds.
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:427) ~[jjwt-impl-0.11.5.jar:0.11.5]
```

...

from client:

```
ERROR
Request failed with status code 403
AxiosError@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:66657:18
settle@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:67310:12
onloadend@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:65992:6
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect its because Spring Security is handling the scenario first.

If you have a `SecurityFilterChain` bean, you should be able to access `HttpSecurity` and do something like this:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
        .oauth2ResourceServer()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(yourAuthenticationEntryPointGoesHere)
        .and()
        .build();
}
```

implement `AuthenticationEntryPoint` and customise the `commence` method.

Comment: What is `AuthenticationEntryPoint` and why should I use it instead of `@ControllerAdvice`? This question is about `@ExceptionHandler` which are defined in `@ControllerAdvice`

Comment: Because its not a controller issue, its a security issue. If you dispensed with spring-security and implemented your own code to read and process the Authorization header in the controller, it would be a controller issue. But spring has nicely abstracted security away from your controller for you.

Comment: But again, how does `commence()` (which I dont know what it is suppose to do) resolves the problem so that `@ExceptionHandler` is called on `ExpiredJwtException`)? I am not going to replace `AuthenticationEntrypoint` with `AdviceController`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).